# DAO Recordset vs Numerous Dlookups

Tags: database, ms-access, vba, dao

I created an access DB for a small business. In this DB I frequently auto fill some text boxes based on a key field via VBA using:

```
me.textboxvalue0.value = Nz(DLookup("VALUE0", "tblsomething", "lookedfield = '" & Me.keyfield.Value & "'"), "")  
me.textboxvalue1.value = Nz(DLookup("VALUE1", "tblsomething", "lookedfield = '" & Me.keyfield.Value & "'"), "")  
me.textboxvalue2.value = Nz(DLookup("VALUE2", "tblsomething", "lookedfield = '" & Me.keyfield.Value & "'"), "")
```

This piece of code repeats for all of my auto fillable textboxes ranging from 2 to 15 txtboxes.
My question is:
Is it faster to open a DAO recordset and find that particular row with all of its fields, or is it faster (execution time) to keep using multiple Dlookups to pull field by field of that row.

Comment: I would use an ADO recordset with "select value0,value1,value2 where lookupfield=" me.lookupid, gives you more options with what to do,  put data back, work off a clone, take to array, count etc.. but can they be bound instead?

Comment: The recordset is definitely faster but whether it is worth implementing depends on how often it happens, how big the database is (will get to be) etc.

Comment: @SunKnight0 The table which is searched on is rather small, up to a maximum of 1000 records. It's just that pulling fields one by one sounded inefficient against pulling the pertinent row. Shame that Dlookup cant return more than one field.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use bound controls? -- *"Shame that Dlookup cant return more than one field."* This is by design, to return multiple fields you use a recordset.

Comment: @Lybren: Actually it can, in a way. Like this: `DLookup("Field1 & ';' & Field2","Table","Condition")`, and then split the result into an array. Clunky but if you had to use DLookup and not proper access to the table it is possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the *OnCurrent* event of the form:

```
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim SQL As String

SQL = "Select * From tblSomething Where lookedfield = '" & Me!keyfield.Value & "'")
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL)
If rst.RecordCount > 0 Then
    Me!textboxvalue0.Value = rst!VALUE0.Value
    Me!textboxvalue1.Value = rst!VALUE1.Value
    Me!textboxvalue2.Value = rst!VALUE2.Value
Else
    Me!textboxvalue0.Value = Null
    Me!textboxvalue1.Value = Null
    Me!textboxvalue2.Value = Null
End If
rst.Close

Set rst = Nothing
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, but this is not the answer to the question.
This is **how** you use DAO recordset. I need an answer as to **which** is faster, multiple dlookups or a DAO recordset find. On a table of 10 to 10000 records.

Comment: Well, then it _is_ the answer. One call will always be faster. Also, this is the type of question I really don't understand because it would have been faster for you to check it out than writing the question. And only you have your data which has the final impact on speed.

Comment: Valuable insight. I will now check on how to do performance tests on access, as I have never done so. But still, when answering a question, explicitly answer with the right words. You start with "you can use", Implying I don't know how to; and not noting that DAO will be faster. Your comment does contain the answer though, "One call will always be faster". Therefore Ill mark your answer.
Yet again, thank you.